# We don't need the new features in SQL Server 2008, but should we upgrade anyway?

Tags: sql-server

We are currently using SQL Server 2005. We don't need the new features in SQL Server 2008 R2, but should we upgrade anyway just to get it over with?

Comment: Isn't that a question for your business?

Comment: I think he's just looking for some reasons why one would NEED to upgrade from 2005 to 2008

Comment: why he would need to upgrade, or someone else?

Comment: You don't need any of the new features, and Microsoft still officially supports SQL Server 2005 .... so why would you want to upgrade?? Never touch a running system! (unless you absolutely have to)

Comment: @marc - I agree with you in principal but you should at least try to stay technologically relevant and up to date. How many versions behind you want to be is up to you. Wait too long and you still see some businesses relying on a VAX.

Comment: @hunter: as long as Microsoft still officially supports it, I'm fine with it. I don't like the SQL Server 2000 projects - too far behind, and there are significant benefits in 2005/2008 vs. 2000 - but between 2005 and 2008 R2, there's just not enough to justify an update without actually **using** those new features....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an article about why you should upgrade:

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server-2000/is-sql-server-2008-r2-for-you-.aspx`

> **Upgrading from 2005: More Functionality**
> If you’re running SQL Server 2005 then there’s a lot of new functionality to be gained by moving to SQL Server 2008 R2. SQL Server 2008 R2 includes the new BI functionality as well as the whole set of SQL Server 2008 features including database and database backup compression; transparent database encryption; new date, time, and spatial data types; new filestream data type; as well as the Resource Governor and policy-based management.

Comment: That article's about upgrading to SQL 2005, he's asking about upgrading _from_ 2005 to SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got something that is working, you don't need any new features, and nobody is forcing the upgrade...why risk breaking what is working just fine?

Answer (score 0):

My take is probably not, BUT, you do need to consider that Mainstream support for Sql Server 2005 will end in April 2011.  This could be very important to your organization, or it could be nothing, just be aware of it.

Based on information found at http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&qid=&alpha=SQL+Server+2005&Filter=FilterNO

Answer (score 0):

From a developer's perspective, being on SQL 2008 gives a couple of nice syntax improvements, i.e.

```
DECLARE @value int = 1
```

instead of

```
DECLARE @value int
SET @value = 1
```

And SQL Server Management Studio 2008 offers intellisense against SQL 2008 databases (assuming you aren't already using SQL Prompt or some other solution).

The [new date data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28SQL.100%29.aspx) are nice if you're able to start using them in new development.

Probably not enough to get an IT department to want to move, but with mainstream support ending in April 2011 (per @[Matthew Vines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185794/we-dont-need-the-new-features-in-sql-server-2008-but-should-we-upgrade-anyway/4185889#4185889)), might be compelling enough to get interested in moving.

Answer (score 0):

If for no other reason, I would upgrade because [mainstream support for SQL Server 2005 is ending on April 12, 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=SQL+Server+2005&Filter=FilterNO).

Answer (score 0):

Not so important to upgrade, IMO. But it could be a chance to upgrade your CV as well :)